# Show that if $m|n$ and $a$ is primitive root modulo $n$, then $a$ is primitive root modulo $m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried some ideas but in the end, noticed that I was assuming that $n=mk$ and $(m,k)=1$, this was not assumed in the question. Now I am stuck as to how to proceed.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I don't quite understand the answer in there.

Comment: The best person to explain the answer is the OP, so I suggest leaving a comment under that answer asking specifically about whatever you don't understand.

Comment: @BillyRubina Agree with asking OP (me) to explain the answer. You should specify what you don't understand.